# Schedule a task using cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have question for cron job,

let say if i would want to schedule a task for every 5 minutes with emailing a copy of df output.

:~$ `crontab -e`

```
5 * * * * df -h
```

the guide says it will sent through email to the user the crontab file belongs to(according to the config file), how do i check that it went through?

When i execute

:~$ `crontab -l`

I'm able to see my schedule task which i've input in.

Or alternatively, is there any chance that i can see the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to run every 5 minutes, the syntax is:

```
*/5 * * * * df -h
```

What you wrote will run it every hour at 5 minutes after the hour.

P.S. Questions like this are more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com.